# Webpack complaining about Vue component type being "any"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

Using ts 4.2.4 and Vue3 Im getting this weird error when building my vue project:

```js
> admin.pacc@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build


⠋  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                  17:36:51

 error  in src/layout/Main.vue:52:20

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './Footer.vue'. '/Users/ddruganov/VSCodeProjects/admin.pacc/src/layout/Footer.vue.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    50 | <script lang="ts">
    51 | import Topbar from "./Topbar.vue";
  > 52 | import Footer from "./Footer.vue";
       |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    53 | import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.vue";
    54 |
    55 | import { activityStore, LOAD_ACTIVITIES } from "@/store/modules/activity.store";

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/ddruganov/VSCodeProjects/admin.pacc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ddruganov/.npm/_logs/2021-05-08T14_36_51_736Z-debug.log
```

Typescript is complaining about my Footer being of type any without complaining about any other .vue component
For some reason VSCode doesnt recognize this as an error:
[image]
You can see that Footer doesnt have the squigglies
Footer code:

```html
<template>
  <footer class="footer bg-light border-top p-3">
    <span class="text-muted">{{ fullYear }} pAcc</span>
  </footer>
</template>

<script land="ts">
import { Vue } from "vue-class-component";

export default class FooterComponent extends Vue {
  get fullYear() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
  }
}
</script>
```

My shims-vue.d.ts file is as follows:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Comment: In the footer, you imported vue fn from `vue-class-component` but there is a Component decorator which needs to import from that package. code: 

`import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// Define the component in class-style
@Component
export default class FooterComponent extends Vue {
  get fullYear() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
  }
}`

Hope this help!

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce the build error in a new Vue CLI scaffolded project, using Vue 3 and TS 4.2.4.

Comment: Also, it seems you have a typo in `Footer.vue` (`land=ts` should be `lang=ts`). Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: @tony19 omg! that is exactly the error that was causing it. this is indeed a type on my code, thank you so much!!! Ill paste your answer as accepted

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad thing is, in all other components I never use "@Component" decorator and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tony19 noticed a typo in my code:

> Also, it seems you have a typo in Footer.vue (land=ts should be lang=ts). Is that just a typo in the question?

Indeed it has to be `lang="ts"`, issue solved, the project now compiles

Answer (score 0):

shims-vue.d.ts

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import { ComponentOptions } from 'vue'
  const component: ComponentOptions
  export default component
}
```

Comment: official vue3-cli created app contains shims-vue.d.ts that has the code that I listed above, replacing DefineComponent with ComponentOptions wont help